# How can I test my Struts 1.2 web application without server?

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-mvc, struts-1

I have a Struts 1.2 web application. It has service & DAO classes as well. How can I test each and every layer without any Web/Application server. I heard, Spring provides the same facility for Spring MVC application. How I can test my application end to end? Please suggest?

Comment: I'd say without a web server you can't test the web layer. Btw, this is an old app, right?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't want to use a server?

Comment: it's 1.2, but in spring we can test web layer without web server.

Comment: yes.deployment in dev server is quite long process & I want to avoid that and in my local I don't have access to install any server.

Comment: I assume you just want to test the actions, right? So no JSP/HTML etc. I assume Spring provides something like a mock server which handles MVC but AFAIK there's no such thing for Struts. You might be able to write one, but I'd suggest reduce the frequency of the tests and use a server along with Selenium for some more complete tests.

Comment: yes, I just wanted to test actions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Struts 1 is officially deprecated and no longer maintained.

In addition, it is hard to imagine developping a web application without a local server on the developpement machine. Eclipse or Netbeans both offer the possibility to use a local Tomcat or [whatever is you prefered servlet container].

Anyway, if corporate policies require it, you could try to search for old tools that were used for Struts 1, hoping you can still find enough resources for them. I can remember :

- [StrutsTestCase for JUnit](http://strutstestcase.sourceforge.net/) : *StrutsTestCase for JUnit is an extension of the standard JUnit TestCase class that provides facilities for testing code based on the Struts framework. StrutsTestCase provides both a Mock Object approach and a Cactus approach to actually run the Struts ActionServlet, allowing you to test your Struts code with or without a running servlet engine.*
- [Apache Cactus](http://attic.apache.org/projects/jakarta-cactus.html) - in the attic since 2011 ... - : *Jakarta previously hosted Cactus, a simple test framework for unit testing server-side java code.*

But beware all those are not maintained for years, and links for documentation are often broken. My advice is to use that as an argument to either switch to a more <del>decent</del> recent framework or be allowed to have a local tomcat.